# Part of waste pipe tilting up

Tags: plumbing

I was clearing the pipes and noticed a part of the waste water pipe was tilting upwards instead of downwards causing a lot of stuff to be congregating at this part and I don't know whether the plumber did that intentionally.

Is there any reason why the plumber decided to connect the pipe this way?

Shouldn't the waste water pipe should always be tilting downwards for the water to flow?

[image]
[image]

Comment: the two elbows should be switched

Comment: Could you another picture to show what connects immediately above this?

Comment: @fuzzydrawings I've added a picture, it's just a pipe that water from the sink and appliances flow into

Comment: So there is no p-trap?

Comment: @fuzzydrawings there is, sorry it's further above not shown in the picture

Comment: Has there been shifting, settling, or subsidence to cause this since it was installed?

Comment: @Criggie I'm nearly 100% sure that there hasn't been. The elbow shown in the picture is solvent welded and I tried to rotate the part of the pipe to make it slope down but couldn't because it is very rigid and solid.

Comment: Also in the pictures you can see there is an end cap in the end, similar to this one https://blanchford.co.uk/marley-waste-abs-50mm-access-cap-white.html, which we can take off to clear the debris out which is exactly what made me wonder whether the guys who did this job intentionally made it this way but for what reason I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

While I cannot answer why your plumber did this, a waste pipe should have a continuous down slope.  If not the result is exactly what you're seeing, "stuff" accumulates where you don't want it to.

This pipe needs to be rerouted properly so it slopes down along its entire length.

Answer (score 2):

Every drain needs a trap to stop sewer gasses, but this does not appear to hold enough water to act like a seal.

This setup appears to be specifically designed to catch debris. I cannot see any other purpose for it. The water comes straight down the pipe then swirls at the tee before flowing up and on down.

**The only possible reason:** To catch heavy impurities that are being put into the drain and to keep the homeowner busy cleaning it.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Can you think of any potential problems if I get this part of the pipe to be redone to get it slope down so that debris do not get caught anymore? This is just a normal kitchen sink, not heavily used and with good strainers and p trap.

Comment: Is low maintenance a problem? Any drain should always be a small downward slope or a vertical. Anything else is a problem. What you have is a problem.

Comment: That's clear, thanks!